# Do we have $A_{(\mathfrak{p})} \simeq (A_{(f)})_{\mathfrak{q}}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, graded-rings

Let $A = \oplus_{d \ge 0} A_d$ be a graded ring.
Let $\mathfrak{p}$ a homogeneous prime of $A$.
Let $f$ be a homogeneous of $A$ of degree $\require{cancel}\cancel{d}$ $1$ such that $f \not\in \mathfrak{p}$.
Let
$$ A_{(\mathfrak{p})} = \Bigl\{ \frac{a}{b} : b \not\in \mathfrak{p}, a, b \text{ homogeneous of same degree} \Bigr\}
  \text{ and }
  A_{(f)} = \Bigl\{ \frac{a}{f^r} : a \in A_{dr} \Bigr\}. $$
Let $\mathfrak{q} = \mathfrak{p} A_f \cap A_{(f)}$.
Do we have $A_{(\mathfrak{p})} \simeq (A_{(f)})_{\mathfrak{q}}$?
We have a well-defined map
$$ \phi : A_{(\mathfrak{p})} \longrightarrow (A_{(f)})_{\mathfrak{q}}, \frac{a}{b} \longmapsto \frac{a/f^r}{b/f^r}$$
where $r = \deg a = \deg b$.
Is this map an isomorphism ?

Comment: Yes, these objects are isomorphic, but there are some light issues with your work: you're implicitly assuming $\deg f=1$ here without actually writing it down. You can prove this in general (i.e. not assuming $\deg f=1$) if you want, and then you'll need to alter your map a bit. Constructing an inverse should be very doable - if you're stumped, see [Stacks 00JR](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00JR) for what the inverse should be (though with some verification steps omitted).